# Потеря .docx при загрузке на/с сервера на php

Tags: php

Есть два скрипта. 1- закачивает с формы файл на сервер

```
req.open("POST", url, true);

req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

+
reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

после чего сохраняется в файле. 2 скрипт отдает файл

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$fileName");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));

echo readfile($fileName);
```

Но при скачивании ворд пишет что файл поврежден, что может быть, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Ваши скрипты где-то выводят еще что-то до того, как вы начнете отдавать файл.

Попробуйте закомментировать строку отдачи файла:

```
// echo readfile($fileName);
```

Затем скачайте файл. Если он будет не нулевого размера, как должен, значит проблема именно такая.

Comment: Файл был и так пуст, не помогло.... Лишнего нечего не писало

Comment: А если загружать файл без использования JS?

Comment: Никак, загружал на сервер файл напрямую и нечего не поменялось (((